# Circleci Jest not Found?

Tags: docker, node-modules, circleci, circleci-2.0

On my local pc, I am able to run 'npm test' command without any error. But when I push my feature branch to Github, Circleci is not able to run my tests and ends up with an error like

```
sh: 1: jest: not found
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
Exited with code 1
```

I am using this Circleci config.yml file and it is not working:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.1.0

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
          - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

      - save_cache:
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
          paths:
            - node_modules
  test:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.1.0

    steps:
      - checkout

      - run:
          name: Test
          command: npm test

      - run:
          name: Generate code coverage
          command: './node_modules/.bin/nyc report --reporter=text-lcov'

      - store_artifacts:
          path: test-results.xml
          prefix: tests

      - store_artifacts:
          path: coverage
          prefix: coverage

workflows:
  version: 2.1
  build_and_test:
    jobs:
      - build
      - test:
          requires:
            - build
```

If I use this config.yml instead, it is working:

```
version: 2.1

jobs:
  build:
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.1.0

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
        keys:
        - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
        - v1-dependencies-

      - run: npm install

  - save_cache:
      paths:
        - node_modules
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

  - run: npm test
```

I am wondering why the first config.yml file is not working? Any clue about this?
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

In the first config, you are running `npm test` in the `test` job. You need to have Jest installed but you never installed it, thus it fails.

In the second config, before `npm test` is ran, `npm install` is run first which I assume is installing Jest.

While you do run `npm install` in the first config, it's ran in the `build` job not the `test` job. Two different jobs, meaning two different containers. They have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: The problem was, in the first config, I have saved the cache but in the Test job, I did not restore the cache, that was missing.

Comment: cna you put your answer into this so we can see the solution